# Is it possible to back-reference an expansion?

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
ln -s foo/bar/{a,b,c} \1
```

which would expand to:

```
ln -s foo/bar/a a
ln -s foo/bar/b b
ln -s foo/bar/c c
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

As an alternative, you can use a for loop:

```
for c in a b c; do ln -s "foo/bar/$c" "$c"; done
```